# Having issues with IAntiforgery in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**Please look at my long answer at the end about how I resolved this.  I had gotten too frustrated and after another day with a fresh perspective and more sleep, I got to a solution.**

I did this in 5.0 with no issues in the `Startup.Configure` method.

Basically I created a header for the request on a protected route. I'm using React as the front end. I'm finding when I place everything in `Program.cs` the dependency injection, authorization doesn't work right so I split up into separate `Program` and `Startup` files.

But I can't use the following signature in 6.0 like I did in 5.0:

example that worked in 5.0:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
{
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>            
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("antiforgery/token", context =>
            {
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Headers.Append("XYZ", tokens.RequestToken!);                    
                return Task.FromResult(StatusCodes.Status200OK);
            });                
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

Program.cs (my attempt to split up program and startup - 6.0)

```
var startup = new dolpassword.Startup(builder.Configuration);
startup.ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

var app = builder.Build();

startup.Configure(app,app.Environment);
```

Saw this example on Microsoft website:

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
// app.Services syntax error in Configure for 6.0
var antiforgery = **app.Services.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();**

 app.Use((context, next) =>
 {
      var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value;

      if (string.Equals(requestPath, "/", 
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            || string.Equals(requestPath, "/index.html", 
              StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var tokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
             context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", 
              tokenSet.RequestToken!,
        new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
         }

         return next(context);
   });
```

Comment: You state you're having issues - specifically what problems?

Comment: There's no ability to put IAntiforgery in the configure method and hence can't create the token.  Microsoft posts a different solution for each version of .NET Core.  Just insane.  I did state the problem - "But I can't use the following signature in 6.0 like I did in 5.0:"

Comment: You state you got an exception. What exception? When things go wrong, you must accurately describe how they go wrong. I understand you're frustrated that it's not working the way you think it should, but that frustration is counter productive to actually solving the problem. You still have to be clear about what you're doing and what's not working.

Comment: I'm trying to create an Antiforgery token for an SPA (React).

Comment: I'm supposed to be giving a presentation  in a few days.  I am not allowed to use 5.0 in the workplace because MS pulled support from it.  I've literally played around with this all weekend and I'm frankly at my wits end.

Comment: We don't really need to know that you're giving a presentation. You already told us that you're doing a React app that's trying to connect to a .NET 6 app that's protected by anyoforgery tokens. You don't need to repeat things, that just wastes time and energy. Instead, please focus on on the problem and what's asked of you. You stated you got an exception - what exception are you talking about?

Comment: I don't receive an exception  I get a 400 error, bad response.  I look in Chrome DevTools, no header is created, no token is created.  But when I try the microsoft solution, it recommends App.Services (generates a syntax error because they are assuming you're going to use Program.cs for the entire configuration).  However, in 5.0 my code works like a charm.  5.0 provides a Configure method that you can place IAntiforgery into the signature.

Comment: Okay, what syntax error? Please be specific. Don't assume we know exactly what's going on.

Comment: You're not going to be able to resolve this unfortunately.  This is a complete mess and I'm going to have to cancel the presentation.  Hours down the drain.  It's pretty sad when a solution that worked perfectly in 5.0, perfectly bombs in 6.0.

Comment: ASP.NET Core 6 supports anti forgery tokens. It's doable, but if you don't actually tell us what's going wrong with your implementation, then you're right, we can't help you. Do you actually want to solve this? Then properly respond with the information requested of you.

Comment: It doesn't support Antiforgery for react.

Comment: I mentioned earlier it's not generating the X-XSRF-TOKEN header in my custom implementation.

Comment: I'm just going to have to plod through this and fix it myself.  May take hours or days but I'm going to put forth the effort.

Comment: You mention a syntax error in your question, but don't bother telling us what the error is. I've asked many times for you to explain the error. If you want help from StackOverflow, you need to actually read and respond to the comments properly.

Comment: Did you know that in .NET 6.0 you can still use you Startup.cs if you want? https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-12-upgrading-a-dotnet-5-startup-based-app-to-dotnet-6/#option-2-re-use-your-startup-class. You can reuse your code that worked on .NET 5.

Comment: I have figured out the solution for this and wanted to post the answer.  Please allow me to reopen this issue.

Comment: That wouldn't be fair to everyone else, as your question still lacks details that would make it where anyone can answer. You were asked repeatedly for it and just ignored those requests. If you edit your question to contain those details, I'll be willing to vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

**I was able to successfully do this in 6.0** so I will share some of the code and how I resolved it.  I also had Windows authentication baked in with a policy-based authorization.  **The reason I'm putting all the authentication/authorization wireup in this post is because the entire solution relies on authentication, authorization and antiforgery.**

First I set up my services.  I get IAntiforgery by default by adding ControllersWithViews but I want to use my own header name, which is X-XSRF-TOKEN instead of the .AspNet.Antiforgery.xxxx or whatever the default is.  I also needed options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; to get Windows auth working.

```
string CorsPolicy = "CorsPolicy";
//===================================formerly Configure Services
WebApplicationBuilder? builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager _configuration = builder.Configuration;
// Add services to the container.
**IServiceCollection? services = builder.Services;
services.AddAntiforgery(options => { options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN"; 
options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false; });**
services.AddTransient<IActiveDirectoryUserService, ActiveDirectoryUserService>();
services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddAuthentication(options => {//needed for Windows authentication
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

Adding more...
I'm using Windows auth so I'm using the Negotiate provider.  Then I set up my Authorization.  I insert my own authorization policy and also add my claims transformers to get the authenticated user into a claim.  The fallback policy in Authorization was causing an Authentication exception.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;//authorization bombs if you include this line
    options.AddPolicy("AuthenticatedOnly", policy => {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthenticatedRequirement(true));
    });    
});
services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, MyClaimsTransformer>();            
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, AppUserRoleHandler>();
services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthenticatedRoleHandler>();
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicy,
    builder => builder
        .WithOrigins("https://localhost:7021","https://localhost:44414") 
         //Note:  The URL must be specified without a trailing slash (/).
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
 });
```

Now I'm in the middleware territory...as you know, order matters in your middleware!  In 5.0 you could add IAntiforgery to your constructor and DI would handle the rest.  In program.cs you don't have that luxury.  Fortunately you can just grab it out of your services collection and you see that in the following code.

```
//==============formerly Startup.Configure=====================
WebApplication app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseCors(CorsPolicy);

IAntiforgery? antiforgery = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();
```

Now when I'm setting up my endpoint routing.  Found out that UseRouting and Use.Endpoints are married at the hip and need to be paired.

I also create a protected route "/auth" (protected by my authorization policy) to grab the antiforgery request token generated when we added it in the services collection.  So this header won't be persisted from request to request like a cookie would.  The minimal API allows me to create a route without creating the controller and action in a separate controller class.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>          
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/auth", context =>
    {        
        var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
        context.Response.Headers.Append("XYZ", tokens.RequestToken!);       
        return Task.FromResult(Results.Ok());
    }).RequireAuthorization("AuthenticatedOnly");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default"
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

My React front end will use a fetch get request to get the token from the headers collection and then stick into a second post request and voila it works.

BTW, React doesn't provide Antiforgery functionality out of the box like Angular, in step with it's minimalist API ethos.

The action I'm posting to looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Policy="AuthenticatedOnly")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public string Update()
```

I fully realize there are other ways to do this.

Comment: Was looking for the same issue - How to get the IAntiforgery service, that helped a lot. Btw, not sure why you got so many frustrating comments on your question - the issue was pretty clear to me. Looks like some people have time to spare.